# VirtualBox BridgedAdapter says "Network not reachable"

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I would like to integrate my VirtualBox VM in bridged mode so that I am able to ping and access other devices in my home network.

As you can see on the following image, I've configured "Bridged Adapter" and configured to my WIFI adapter which is currently in use.

[image: Linux VM Settings]

But if I try to ping an other device in my network I'll get the following error message:

> ping: connect: Network is unreachable

What do I need to do more that this works? Or is the bridged mode the wrong thing?

Edit:

Some more informations:

- `ip route show` displays nothing.
- `ifconfig` displays two options; `lo` with `inet=127.0.0.1 / netmask 255.0.0.0` and `eth0` without the inet and netmask parameter.

Advanced settings:

[image: Advanced settings]

Comment: What do you have set in Advanced?

Comment: @Tetsujin I've added a screenshot.

Comment: Bridging Wi-Fi client interfaces is not possible most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

The article
[How To Use Your Wireless Adapter With VirtualBox Bridge Mode](https://www.revolutionweb.com.au/computer-security/use-wireless-adapter-virtualbox-bridge-mode/)
proposes the following method:

- Run on the host the command `ifconfig` (Linux) or `ipconfig /all` (Windows)
- Take note or copy the MAC address of the WiFi adapter
- In the VirtualBox adapter setting, click Adavnced and set
  "MAC address" to this same value.

See the above article for more details and screenshots.